# Как убрать opacity у дочернего элемента?

Tags: opacity, css

Есть примерно такой код:

```
<div id="block1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">
<div id="block2" style="width: 300px; height: 150px; background-color: #000; color: #fff; opacity: 0.2;">
<div id="block3" style="opacity: 1;">
test test test
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Вот тут реализация на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/U5CLR/

Как убрать opacity (точнее вернуть его к значению 1) для блока #block3?

Спасибо.

Comment: Наследование. Нужно вынести наружу block3, за пределы block2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выхода два:

а) Избавиться от наследования, вынести `#block3` из `#block2`;

б) Избавиться от `opacity`, заменив его `rgba(...)` для цветов и полупрозрачными `*.png` для изображений.

Comment: вероятно, rgba?

Comment: @VladD, опечатка :)

Answer (score 1):

полупрозрачность:

```
#block2
{
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); /*красный цвет поменяете на свой*/
}
```

opacity убрать надо везде

Comment: Собственно, это и написано в моём ответе, зачем дублировать?

Comment: @A_Gontarev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, заменить бг на полупрозрачный пнг!