# Как убрать opacity определенного виджета внутри дочернего opacity виджета?

Tags: flutter, opacity

Как убрать `opacity` определенного виджета внутри дочернего `opacity` виджета?

Я не могу снять opacity а только сделать более прозрачным `opacity: 1` не работает

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.5,
  child: Card(
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: 1,
      child: Container(child: event.text),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, вместо opacity можно использовать rgba, тогда должно получиться

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-opacity-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Приведите примеры кода. Как нам понять что и где вы хотите убрать?

Comment: @MiT Привел пример

Comment: @NoProgress а теперь объясните что вы пытаетесь сделать из этого примера. У какого виджетов вы хотите убрать opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас не на ПК, но думаю это поможет:

```
Card(
    elevation: 0, 
    color: Colors.transparent, 
    child: ...
)
```

Comment: Теперь я понял, нужно было работать с прозрачностью цвета, а не использовать Opacity() виджет